# React tutorial is not crashing without handleClick. How is it working?

Tags: reactjs

I just started learning react. I am following the tutorial. The guide and my logic tell me that the code should not work. but it is still working. I got to a point where the tutorial says the code will crash.

> We have not defined the `handleClick()` method yet, so our code crashes.

But **my code still continues working**. I thought it might have been that it is still running the old version of the code. So I refreshed the page and also rerun the npm start. None of it seems to help.

Here is my code. As you can see I have nowhere defined `handleClick()`, but **the game is still working**. I don't get how.

```js
class Square extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button
          className="square"
          onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
        >
          {this.props.value}
        </button>
      );
    }
  }

  class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      };
    }

    renderSquare(i) {
        return (
          <Square
            value={this.state.squares[i]}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
          />
        );
    }

    render() {
      const status = 'Next player: X';

      return (
        <div>
          <div className="status">{status}</div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(0)}{this.renderSquare(1)}{this.renderSquare(2)}
          </div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(3)}{this.renderSquare(4)}{this.renderSquare(5)}
          </div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(6)}{this.renderSquare(7)}{this.renderSquare(8)}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  class Game extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="game">
          <div className="game-board">
            <Board />
          </div>
          <div className="game-info">
            <div>{/* status */}</div>
            <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  // ========================================

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Game />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

---

**Why is the code still working without `handleClick()`?**

Comment: You need to rebuild the app again before starting the app. You will get the error then

Comment: I haven't run command npm run build yet. I just use npm start. I thought it rebuilds the app every time I do npm start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved the my-app folder into a new folder. Since I haven't closed my editor the vscode made copy of the files that I was working and placed them on desktop. In my editor I was seeing the wrong files but the terminal was running in the correct directory. That explains that the app wasn't updating on save. You don't need to rebuild the app at all react does it for you.

```
npm run build
```

run build is for production build and is not relevant.

Sorry for stupid question. It was really confusing at the moment. **The lesson - Do not move the project folder while open in vscode. If you do reopen the vscode in proper folder.**

Comment: Ah, your file wasn't saved?

Comment: It was saving as another file. The npm start was running different one.

Comment: ha, it happens sometime.

Answer (score 1):

The Square component has just onClick props and the event will be called only after you actually click on the button which is provided in the component. So, the error will only appear after you click on the button. At that time your app will crash but not just after you start the project.

If still doesn't (due to cache), then try with following commands or try clearing the browser cache:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm start
```

Comment: It doesn't crash after the click either.

Comment: I posted what happened as an answer.

Comment: your answer was useful. My bad about the situation.